# Java Exit MouseListener if CheckBoxMenuItem is unchecked

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, mouselistener, jmenubar

I have created a menu bar with some entries and one of them is a CheckBoxMenuItem.
I want to perform a MouseListener event if that item is checked and I want it to stop with that if I uncheck it.

In addition to that, I have created a JPanel on which mouse events can be performed and a status bar.

To resolve that problem I thought of an if-loop:

```
clickItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                   if (clickItem.getState() == true) {
                       mousePanel.addMouseListener(mouseHandler);
                       mousePanel.addMouseMotionListener(mouseHandler);
                   }
                   else if (clickItem.getState() == false) {                           
                       statusBar.setText("Mouse Mode OFF");
                   }    
               }
           });
```

But if I run my program with this code, the panel with the mouse events doesn't switch off if I uncheck the check box.

What's wrong?

Edit:

```
private JLabel statusBar;
private JPanel mousePanel;


private class HandlerClass implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

// Mouse events for MouseListener

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {

statusBar.setText(String.format("Clicked at %d %d", event.getX(), event.getY()));
        }
...

HandlerClass mouseHandler = new HandlerClass();
```

Comment: You are adding mouselistener everytime you click the check box. That is not correct, you should add listener once. Please post an [MCVE](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi0zr-5pN7UAhWOa1AKHWSIBCMQFggrMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fhelp%2Fmcve&usg=AFQjCNHreFGjawnJ-ucm2EGso8qxNscnMA) to get better help.

Comment: Did you add an output to see if the method is called? What about your if/elseif?

Comment: I don't get the Mouse Mode Off Text

Added some code, maybe this helps for further understanding. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: Better to simply change the state of the model when the check box menu item is checked or unchecked. Your mouse listener can query the state of the model when mouse events occur.

Answer (score 1):

OK, overkill, I know, but consider doing a Model-View-Controller set up, where the view is as stupid as possible. All it does is create its components for display and that's it. The model holds the state of the checkbox, it holds the location and state of the mouse -- whether it was pressed, is dragging or is released. The model can use Java Bean's property listener support so that the controller can add listeners to it and be notified of state changes. The whole thing could look like:

```
import javax.swing.*;

// main program that creates the model and view and plugs them into 
// the controller
public class SimpleMvc {
    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        SimpleModel model = new SimpleModel();
        SimpleView view = new SimpleView();
        new SimpleController(model, view);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Simple MVC");
        frame.setJMenuBar(view.getJMenuBar());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(view.getMainPanel());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import javax.swing.event.SwingPropertyChangeSupport;

// model that holds the state of the program
// and notifies listeners of changes in this state
public class SimpleModel {
    public static final String CHECK_STATE = "check state";
    public static final String MOUSE_POINT = "mouse point";
    public static final String MOUSE_STATE = "mouse state";
    private SwingPropertyChangeSupport support = new SwingPropertyChangeSupport(this);
    private boolean checkState = false;
    private Point mousePoint = null;
    private SimpleMouseState mouseState = SimpleMouseState.RELEASED;

    public boolean isCheckState() {
        return checkState;
    }

    public void setCheckState(boolean checkState) {
        boolean oldValue = this.checkState;
        boolean newValue = checkState;
        this.checkState = checkState;

        // notify the listeners of the change
        support.firePropertyChange(CHECK_STATE, oldValue, newValue);
    }

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(String propertyName, PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        support.addPropertyChangeListener(propertyName, listener);
    }

    public Point getMousePoint() {
        return mousePoint;
    }

    public void setMousePoint(Point mousePoint) {
        Point oldValue = this.mousePoint;
        Point newValue = mousePoint;
        this.mousePoint = mousePoint;
        support.firePropertyChange(MOUSE_POINT, oldValue, newValue);
    }

    public SimpleMouseState getMouseState() {
        return mouseState;
    }

    public void setMouseState(SimpleMouseState mouseState) {
        SimpleMouseState oldValue = this.mouseState;
        SimpleMouseState newValue = mouseState;
        this.mouseState = mouseState;
        support.firePropertyChange(MOUSE_STATE, oldValue, newValue);
    }    
}
```

```
// enum to encapsulate the mouse state
public enum SimpleMouseState {
    PRESSED("Pressed"),
    DRAGGED("Dragged"),
    RELEASED("Released");
    private String text;

    private SimpleMouseState(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
}
```

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

// our view, again make it as dumb as possible
// all the "brains" are in the model and controller
public class SimpleView {
    private static final int PREF_W = 600;
    private static final int PREF_H = 450;
    private JComponent mainPanel = new JPanel();
    private JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    private JLabel statusLabel = new JLabel("  ");

    public SimpleView() {
        JPanel statusPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
        statusPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
        statusPanel.add(statusLabel);

        mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H));
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        mainPanel.add(statusPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    public JComponent getMainPanel() {
        return mainPanel;
    }

    public JMenuBar getJMenuBar() {
        return menuBar;
    }

    public void setStatusMessage(String text) {
        statusLabel.setText(text);
    }

}
```

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;

import javax.swing.JCheckBoxMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JMenu;

// our controller, where we hook everything together
public class SimpleController {
    public static final String MOUSE_MODE_OFF = "Mouse Mode OFF";
    public static final String MOUSE_MODE_ON = "Mouse Mode ON";
    private SimpleModel model;
    private SimpleView view;
    private JCheckBoxMenuItem clickItem = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Click Me");

    public SimpleController(SimpleModel model, SimpleView view) {
        this.model = model;
        this.view = view;
        view.setStatusMessage(MOUSE_MODE_OFF);

        // Add view listeners
        clickItem.addItemListener(new ViewClickItemListener());
        JMenu menu = new JMenu("Menu");
        menu.add(clickItem);
        view.getJMenuBar().add(menu);
        ViewMouseListener mouseListener = new ViewMouseListener();
        view.getMainPanel().addMouseListener(mouseListener);
        view.getMainPanel().addMouseMotionListener(mouseListener);

        // add model listeners
        model.addPropertyChangeListener(SimpleModel.CHECK_STATE, new ModelCheckStateListener());
        model.addPropertyChangeListener(SimpleModel.MOUSE_POINT, new ModelMousePointListener());
        model.addPropertyChangeListener(SimpleModel.MOUSE_STATE, new ModelMouseStateListener());
    }

    private class ModelMousePointListener implements PropertyChangeListener {
        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            Point p = (Point) evt.getNewValue();
            String text = model.getMouseState().getText();
            view.setStatusMessage(String.format("%s at [%03d, %03d]", text, p.x, p.y));            
        }
    }

    private class ModelMouseStateListener implements PropertyChangeListener {
        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            Point p = model.getMousePoint();
            String text = model.getMouseState().getText();
            if (p == null) {
                return;
            }
            view.setStatusMessage(String.format("%s at [%03d, %03d]", text, p.x, p.y));            
        }
    }

    private class ModelCheckStateListener implements PropertyChangeListener {
        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            if ((boolean) evt.getNewValue()) {
                view.setStatusMessage(MOUSE_MODE_ON);
            } else {
                view.setStatusMessage(MOUSE_MODE_OFF);
            }
        }
    }

    private class ViewClickItemListener implements ItemListener {
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            model.setCheckState(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED);
        }
    }

    private class ViewMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            // check model's check state first
            if (model.isCheckState()) {
                // mouse listener is active -- change the model's state
                model.setMouseState(SimpleMouseState.PRESSED);
                model.setMousePoint(e.getPoint());
            } // else do nothing
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            // similar to mouse pressed
            if (model.isCheckState()) {
                model.setMouseState(SimpleMouseState.DRAGGED);
                model.setMousePoint(e.getPoint());
            } // else do nothing            
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            // similar to mouse pressed
            if (model.isCheckState()) {
                model.setMouseState(SimpleMouseState.RELEASED);
                model.setMousePoint(e.getPoint());
            } // else do nothing            
        }
    }
}
```